# Close Application if no internet connection

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, android-internet

OnCreate of my "Home" activity, I want to check if there's internet connection, if false just close my activity showing a toast..
But, my Home Activity could not be the first on stack, so if just set finish(); it could just close this activity and show the top one in activity stack..

So I've written down this code, but does it make any sense?

```
 if(!Utils.isOnline(mContext))
        if(!moveTaskToBack(true))
            finish();
```

Where Utils.isOnline() is just my method to check internet connection

**EDIT**: I've already created my method to check internet connection and it's Utils.isOnline().. So I'm not asking how to check internet connectio...

**EDIT2**: moveTaskToBack() probably is not best choice to achieve my target, because yes it puts my activity onBackGround but if I reopen it, app doesn't check anymore my condition (Don't know why.. it skips onCreate(?)) and shows a blank activity..

Comment: Android apps should not close. Why not just let the user know there is no connection.

Comment: What's it supposed to do if `moveTaskToBack()` returns false? Nothing?

Comment: Because user can't do anything in my app without internet connection.. So just want to show a toast (didn't write in code) but close application (or put in background).

Comment: @Geobits moveTaskToBack() should move Task to bottom of backstack, shouldn't? and returns True if works, false otherwise.. So I think "well, if doesn't put on background I close activity"..

Comment: Do you want to continious internet connection and if net connection is false, close application ?

Comment: @Antonio Cali Did you found a solution?

Comment: Yeah at the end yes.. But It's quite strange my homepage extends fragment list so I had to put same control on Activity and on Fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to close your app you can add this lines:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
       intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Reading Android Developers Guide they discourage to "KILL" process, so I'd like to use some guideline method

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

put following condition in onCreate().

```
if(!Utils.isOnline(mContext)){


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have no Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
    finish(); 
}
```